# Python3: Comparing two CSV Files to identify what's new in the newer File, ignoring content that was in the oldfile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to compare two csv files with pandas and identify changes.
My goal is to identify the new entrys that are present in the new file but not in the old, ignoring everything that was in the old file and isn't available anymore in the newer.

1. an old file

```
NAME;DESCRIPTION;LINK;PRICE;IMAGE
Item4;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item3;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item2;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item1;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
```

2. a newer file

```
NAME;DESCRIPTION;LINK;PRICE;IMAGE
Item5;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item4;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item3;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
Item2;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
```

I already got so far to identify any changes between both files but unfortunately it also displays waht doesn't exist in the new file anymore

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('csv/new.items.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('csv/old.items.csv')
c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)

c.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
c.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)
c.to_csv(r'csv/pd.items.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Expected result should be a new file including only the new entry which wasn't found in the old file

```
NAME;DESCRIPTION;LINK;PRICE;IMAGE
Item5;something;https://example.com;10;https://example.com/image.jpg
```

haven't worked with python for years so don't be too hard on me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
c = b.merge(a, how = 'left', on = 'NAME', suffixes = ("", "_y"))

you should be able to get the new ones using the below command

c[c.DESCRIPTION_y.isnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work due to KeyError issues on my csv's but it led me to another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end by doing the following

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('csv/new.items.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('csv/old.items.csv')


d = b.merge(a, how='inner', on=None, suffixes=("", "_y"))
d.to_csv(r'csv/old.items.csv', index=False, header=True)

b = pd.read_csv('csv/old.items.csv')
c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)
c.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True) # Set keep to False if you don't want any
c.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)
c.to_csv(r'csv/pd.items.csv', index=False, header=True)
```